# Java based open source deployment framework

Tags: deployment

I am looking for an open source deployment framework (java based). It should have following high level capabilities:

1. Posibility of registering deployment handlers for each artifact type
2. The framework should define a metadata format for defining the
   artifacts. The framework should read a package (exm a zip file), load the metadata file
   and invoke handlers for each artifacts packaged.

Where i want to use this framrwork?
I want to use this framework to deploy composite application packages (containing jar files, bpm models, rule models, ear files etc). On deploy the artifacts should get deployed to their respective runtimes.

Please let me know if you are aware of such an open source framework.

Thanks,
Siddharth