# App packaging and deploy frameworkH

Tags: deployment

Are you familiar with any open source java based app packaging a deployment framework?
I want to use the framework to deploy composite apps. The framework should allow registration of deploy handlers for deploying specific components.

Thanks,
Sidd

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java based open source deployment framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076505/java-based-open-source-deployment-framework)